# discord.py Support VoiceChannel bot

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to create a Voice channel if someone joins the voice channel a voicechannel named "Support for username" gets created, but im struggeling i dont even have a Example code written because i dont know how it works.

Could you guys help me? would be AMAZING :D

Answer (score 0):

Look like you need to flesh out your process first:

1. The bot listens for users joining voice channels ([event reference here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update))
2. When a user joins a voice channel, check if the channels id equals the id of the main support channel
3. If so create a new channel ([reference here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel)) using the sender's name (ctx.author or message.author)

Please tell me if that helped